# SAX Parser not working

Tags: java, xml, sax

I'm trying to read an xml file using sax in java. I only get output for the endelement but I can't find out what's wrong with the startElement.

This is my handler:

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
System.out.println( "SAX Event: START ELEMENT[ " + localName + " ]" );
}

public void endElement( String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName ) throws SAXException {
System.out.println( "SAX Event: END ELEMENT[ " + localName + " ]" );
}
```

}

I test it with the following code:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
{
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
saxParser.parse("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", new XMLHandler());
}
```

I use an example XML file from w3schools:

```
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and this is my output:

```
SAX Event: END ELEMENT[ to ]
SAX Event: END ELEMENT[ from ]
SAX Event: END ELEMENT[ heading ]
SAX Event: END ELEMENT[ body ]
SAX Event: END ELEMENT[ note ]
```

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: I take it `new ProtrackXMLHandler()` is a cut/paste mistake, or is the `ProtrackXMLHandler` class different from XMLHandler class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your method prototypes are incorrect.  this is why you should always use the @Override annotation.  you probably imported the wrong Attributes class?

Comment: I imported java.util.jar.Attributes instead of org.xml.sax.Attributes, thank you